# Forcing post request to finish submitting before new page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the jQuery $.post method to submit an ajax request to a PHP script whenever a certain element is clicked. I don't care about the value returned by the server - I just want to make sure that my data is submitted.

However, the element that receives the click could contain either a hyperlinked image or a flash element with several links in it. How can I ensure that my script receives the post request (again, I don't care about its response) even if the user navigates away from the page? I am using the code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".click-track").mousedown(function(e) { // click() will not pass through a flash movie, so we must use mousedown
        ad_id = $(this).data("ad-id");
        var data = {
            action: 'log_click',
            adId: ad_id
        };
        $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
        $.post(myscript.php, data, function(data) {
            // Do nothing because we don't care about the response
        }, 'html');
    });
});
```

I'm no browser scripting guru, and this code has me flummoxed. I would appreciate any help you could give!

Comment: I realized that all of the flash videos opened their links in a new window, so I modified the script that generated the elements I was working with and added a target="_blank" to the anchor element. If everything is opening in a new window/tab, my original problem is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do an e.preventDefault() within the mousedown handler, you can simply do this inside the $.post call:

```
$(".click-track").mousedown(function(e) { // click() will not pass through a flash movie, so we must use mousedown
    e.preventDefault();
    ad_id = $(this).data("ad-id");
    var data = {
        action: 'log_click',
        adId: ad_id
    };
    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    var jqxhr = $.post(myscript.php, data, function(data) {
        // Do nothing because we don't care about the response

    }, 'html');
    jqxhr.complete(function(){ $(this).trigger('click'); });
});
```

This should create an ajax object and attach a function when the POST request completes that should trigger a click on the originally mousedown'd element. I've gotten this to work with non-Flash elements, not sure if it will work on the Flash object, but it should.

Comment: I can see that this is the best way of going about it, but I still can't seem to get it to work with the Flash object. I'm not sure that there is a way around this one... I ended up developing a "work-around", as you can see from my comment on my original post. I'd love to see a way to get this working with Flash!

Answer (score 1):

Handle the redirect in Javascript, and make it happen after you get a response.  Also, you probably don't want AJAX -- you probably want a synchronous post.

Comment: If the element receiving the click is a flash video, how can I get the URL that it should redirect to?

Comment: Maybe this doesn't work, but perhaps you could put the flash video into a container element and have an onclick event for that element?  Adobe stuff can get pretty bossy so this might not work.

Comment: I was checking into that, and it looks like currently, the only reliable, cross-browser way to do that is to use a mousedown event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force you code to block until the post finishes, I suggest using .ajax() instead and set the async field to false. Like so:

```
$.ajax({
 //some fields
 async:false,
 //some more fields
});
```

Now, your js will block until the call returns. Though I will warn you this is not preferred.

Edit: If the element is a hyperlink you will need to call event.preventDefault(). It is also worthwhile to set the link's href attribute to "javascript:void(0);".